# How do I transplant multiple branches onto a new test branch in git

Tags: git, branch

I have a git repository with number of branches, each of which represents a single feature or fix. I want to create a new branch that includes *all* of those branches, for testing, but I do not want to change or remove the existing branches, nor do I want to affect master. What's the best way of doing this?

So what I have is, in effect

```
                      -- G -- H [feature1]
                     /
A -- B ---------- C -- D [master]
  \ -- E [fix1] \
                 \ -- F [fix2]
```

and I want to achieve

```
                      -- G -- H [feature1]
                     /
A -- B ---------- C -- D [master] -
  \ -- E [fix1] \                   \
                 \ -- F [fix2]       \
                                      \ -- E -- F -- G -- H [test-them-all]
```

I could just clone the repo, merge the branches in the clone, and test against master on the clone. That's simple, and I guess less risky than playing games with branches, but I'm curious if it's possible to do it within a single repo?

Answer (score 0):

from your diagram, I'm assuming you want to use rebase to get fast forward merges. (warning, I haven't tested all these commands, use them as a guide not absolute truth :))

Create a second branch at the tip of each branch (so you can do rebases without rolling back).

```
git checkout fix1
git checkout -b fix1-test

git checkout fix2
git checkout -b fix2-test

git checkout feature1
git checkout -b feature1-test

git checkout master
git checkout -b test-them-all
```

Rebase the fixes and feature into the test-them-all branch

```
git checkout fix1
git rebase test-them-all
git checkout test-them-all
git rebase fix1

git checkout fix2
git rebase test-them-all
git checkout test-them-all
git rebase fix2

git checkout feature1
git rebase test-them-all
git checkout test-them-all
git rebase feature1
```

Then do your tests on the test-them-all branch, assuming they pass and you don't have any new commits to master:

```
git checkout master
git rebase test-them-all
```

to go back to your original state instead, delete all the test branches